# Is it possible to log in to DB rather than whole domain?

Tags: php, mysql

This might seem a very basic question but I can't find an answer for it.

I log in to my (mysql) database but when I go to other websites of mine I am still logged in from the other site. (dbhost:localhost, dbname:databasename)

What am I doing wrong? I thought that logging into that database would be for that database specifically rather than all my databases.

I am using a 'connect' file, with PDO

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",$dbuser,$dbpass);
```

EDIT: I was using the same session variable for login ID across different sites connecting to different databases. Happy for this question to be closed.

Comment: You haven't posted any code so this is likely to get closed. What code are you using, and how does it differ on the "other websites of mine"?

Comment: Hi, if you are voting to close this question, please refer me to what you think is the answer.

Comment: How exactly are you "logging into a database" and how exactly are you determining that you're "still logged into the database"…?

Comment: sorry - 'connecting' to the database. I am determining that I am still logged in by $session variable, I shall look into this more closely.

Comment: @gavin the user that connects to your MySQL database, and PHP's `$_SESSION` variable (assuming that's what you meant) are two completely different things. Just because you're "logged in" (as in connected) to a database does not mean you are logged in (or out) of a web application.

Comment: @Andy yes - I think the problem is that I am conflating the two

Comment: @gavin ok that explains it. The code you've posted for the PDO connection is merely used to allow PHP to communicate with your MySQL database - it has nothing to do with "users" of your application. In terms of logging users in/out of the application, that's a whole different topic - look up some tutorials on a PHP login system & session management, and that should help.

Comment: Thanks@Andy, I see. Should I delete this question as I now realise it is not a proper question?

Comment: I'm not a moderator so not sure - sometimes you can't delete them. I think from the comments it's clear what's happened though :)

Answer (score 1):

With each database installation, there is a single root user (and possibly more than one administrative user) that has access to all the databases in the installation. Then, for each individual database, you can assign a variety of users with a variety of permissions such as read only, etc. It's good practice on a system with multiple databases to create users for each one so you don't get any cross-over. This is especially true for any production database, or staging database with sensitive information.

Comment: this is usually true, but not always true. [actually, statistically, most databases doesn't have a single root account](http://sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html)

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what I thought I was doing: I am connecting with a user that I thought was dedicated to that DB, but I am unsure now. Is it because that user's  host is localhost?

Comment: Localhost doesn't have anything to do with it, it's how the installation was set up. And @hanshenrik, you're correct, but I was trying to keep it simple. Especially considering it was tagged as MySQL.

Comment: @gavin - there is a database called `mysql` which will be on your system. In there, there are some tables such as `db`, `tables_priv` and `user`. I'd recommend having a look at those tables (using phpMyAdmin, Navicat, or some equivalent). You should be able to determine what the user you're connecting with has access to. All it sounds like is that you've connected using something like the root user, which has access and full privileges on all databases. So in other words your connection will connect to "any" database on your system.

Comment: @Andy thanks. I will look at that, as I wasn't aware of that.